# Sigmoid functions similar to atan but with different upper and lower bound

Tags: functions, smooth-functions

Do there exist **smooth** sigmoid functions similar to atan but with different upper and lower bounds? This function must go through origin.
Something like on the picture: [Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iOf8.png)
If not, why? Where can I get more info about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to math.stackexhange. You can transform any standard sigmoidal function $f$ such as $f = \arctan$ or the hyperbolic tangent $f = \tanh$ by

- Multiplying $f$ with a constant, $f(x)$ becomes $cf(x)$
- Shifting the graph to the left or the right so that is still passes through the origin, $f(x)$ becomes $f(x + b) - f(b)$

Combining these, new functions $g(x) = c(f(x + b) - f(b))$ can be made that are increasing, have desired limits at $\pm \infty$, and satisfy $g(0) = 0$.

For example, $g(x) = 4(\arctan(x + 1) - \arctan(1))$ has limits $- 3\pi$ at $- \infty$, $\pi$ at  $\infty$, and $g(0) = 0$. See the graph. [image]

Comment: Wow, many thanks! It's really clarifying answer.